# How activate completion in user shell console?

Tags: bash, debian

When I uncomment next part in `/etc/bash.bashrc`  for activate completion,

```
  #      enable bash completion in interactive shells                                                                                                                                                
     if ! shopt -oq posix; then                                                                                                                                                                   
       if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then                                                                                                                                 
         . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion                                                                                                                                             
       elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then                                                                                                                                                     
         . /etc/bash_completion                                                                                                                                                                   
       fi                                                                                                                                                                                         
     fi
```

I get next error: (`type -a completion`)

> completion: not found

What my next steps?

Comment: Does the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` exist? If yes, what are its contents? If not, what are the contents of `/etc/bash_completion`? The error lies there, not in the bash.bashrc.

Comment: @StefanM this file exist and contents some bash script

Comment: If you want your problem solved, you should post these contents? :)

Comment: I find answer :
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash <username> in https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-tab-complete-not-working